# print error: commandtops crashed on signal 11

Tags: 16.04, printing

I am trying to install an OKI MC362 network printer on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (x86_64 box). When doing the first "Print Test Page" the printer spat out a blank page, with the only following words: "Media Limits". The job was shown by the printer queue as being completed.

I tried a "Print Self-Test Page", which stopped with A "Printer error". Looking at the `/var/log/cups/error_log`, I saw the following line:

```
[Job 125] PID 3071 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/commandtops) crashed on signal 11
```

And

```
[Job 125] printer-state-message="Filter failed"

[Job 125] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Anyone knows what this means and what my problem might be?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping cups, uninstalling it and reinstalling it solved my problem.